# can we use ImageUrl AugmentedImageDatabase?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to create an Image detection app using Arcore.
I want to know that is there any way we can create Arreference Image without added into the augmented database like ARkit. ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get a solution @Rahul ?

Comment: No, @IdrisStack, in the end, I have to use the Vuforia library because there is nothing much about Arcore.

Comment: Hey Rahul, can you share any resource for that ?